# Output result and update 2nd table without using a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I currently have the following query

```
SELECT TOP (@batchSize) * into #t 
from iv.SomeView
where EXISTS(select * 
             from iv.PendingChanges 
             where SomeView.RecordGuid = PendingChanges .RecordGuid)

update iv.PendingChanges
set IsQueued = 1
where RecordGuid in (select #t.RecordGuid from #t)

select * from #t
```

This pattern (using different views and `PendingChanges` tables in the various queries) is run very frequently and I was trying to figure out how to reduce the writes to `tempdb` due to the write to `#t`.

I came up with this solution which does have a performance boost when comparing it to the old version in the profiler

```
select top (0) * into #t from iv.SomeView

insert into #t with (TABLOCK)
output inserted.*
SELECT TOP (@batchSize) *
from iv.SomeView
where EXISTS(select * 
             from iv.PendingChanges 
             where SomeView.RecordGuid = PendingChanges.RecordGuid)

update iv.PendingChanges
set IsQueued = 1
where RecordGuid in (select #t.RecordGuid from #t)
```

But is there any way to do this even better so I can both get the result outputted and update `PendingChanges.IsQueued` without ever needing to write the result out temporarily to `#t`?

**Important note:** I can only have a single `select` from `iv.SomeView` because the table is very active and doing multiple `SELECT TOP (@batchSize)` is not deterministic nor do I have any field I could order by to make it so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried code like :

```
update top (@batchsize) PC 
Set IsQueued = 1
    output inserted.*
From iv.PendingChanges PC 
inner join iv.SomeView SV
on iv.SomeView.RecordGuid = iv.PendingChanges.RecordGuid;
```